# Python gsheets, when trying to get an output from a cell, it gives me a really big string that is us

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a small database for some future programs and I'm just testing [gsheets](https://pypi.org/project/gsheets/) and I want to make a simple counter, everything is going well except for the output that a cell gives me.

It outputs `"Cell R1C1 '2'"` and I don't know how to convert that to an actual variable that I'd actually use.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('My Project-b417d3513158.json', scope)

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)

sheet = client.open('Database').sheet1

result = sheet.cell(1,1)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using gsheets, you are using [gspread](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/).

You're are very close, just use the `value` attribute on `sheet.cell` see [here](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#getting-a-cell-value)

```
result = sheet.cell(1,1).value
```